# What is the reason for rel='stylesheet'?

Tags: html, css

When linking a CSS stylesheet to the HTML page I see this code:

```
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

I understand `href='style.css'` is telling the code to link to my 'style.css' page.

But what is the reason for the second part? = `rel='stylesheet'`. Will this ever change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many potential `rel` values. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp Stylesheet is the most common by far, but the others definitely exist.

Answer (score 4):

The `rel='stylesheet'` attribute is used to define the relationship between the linked file and the current HTML document.

The `rel` stands for "relationship", and is probably one of the key features of the `<link>` element — the value denotes how the item being linked to is related to the containing current document.

The current HTML document needs to tell the browser what you were linking to using the `rel` tag, otherwise the browser would have no idea what to do with the content you're linking to.

There are many different kinds of relationship. Like @cee
You will find the list of some of `Link` types in the following [links](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp)

[Refer this link for more details from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)

Answer (score 2):

`<link` tags are not inherently CSS style sheets. There are lots of `link` types, for example `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">`.

If you didn't tell the browser what you were linking to via `rel`, then the browser would have no idea what to do with the content you're linking to.